# Back end already in use

Tags: windows, permissions, microsoft-access, database, database-administration

We are using an Access Database divided in front end and back end (in a shared folder). I distributed copies of the front end to every user. All users have the shared folder and subfolders added to trusted locations and settings to open as shared, no locks. All users also have read/write permissions on the folder. I still get an error stating that the back end is already in use when a second user tries to open the front end.

Trusted locations:

[image]

Permissions:

[image]

[updated 31/03/2016] I still haven´t surrendered. I finally got some guys from IT to come and check everything. We repaired Access, checked permissions and more. As it turns out, if the IT guy opens it first, everyone else can use it simultaneously, but if one of us opens it first, no one else (not even the IT guy with Administrator privileges) can open it. Any recommendations?

Comment: Change the `Default open mode` to **Shared** and you shouldn't get the error.  If you don't know how to do that, do what I did, **Google it**.  Since I searched for the answer, I now know the answer, and knowing is half the battle

Comment: *Caveat*: Access has intentionally limited concurrency control. If multiple users access Access simultaneously, results may be unpredictable. You might be better served with a true client-server database system, whether free Firebird, SQLite, SQL Server Express Edition, or even a commercial product.

Comment: All default open modes are set shared also.

Comment: I still haven´t surrendered. I finally got some guys from IT to come and check everything. We repaired Access, checked permissions and more. As it turns out, if the IT guy opens it first, everyone else can use it simultaneously, but if one of us opens it first, no one else (not even the IT guy with Administrator privileges) can open it. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem multiple times. The solution is simple (but not obvious):

In the Access options -> client options check "legacy encryption".

You have to do that for each client ( / Access installation / workstation).
See the attached screenshot. The options in English:

- Shared
- No Locks
- Open databases using record-level locking
- Use legacy encryption.

The last option, legacy encryption, is the most important one in a multi-user environment.

[image: Access client options]

Comment: Can you please provide English translations for the yellow highlighted text? (Assuming the highlight is important for some reason).

Comment: From the positions I´m guessing: "Shared", "No Locks", "Open databases using record-level locking", and finally "Use legacy encryption...". If that is it, it did not work for me, I still get the "Back end in use" message after changing the settings for the different users. Any other ideas please?

Comment: Your translation is correct. You have to make sure, that **all** users have the "Use legacy encryption" option set. Please ensure also, that **all** users close the database. Once, it took us a week to find out that one user had the database permanently open. After he had closed the database and we changed his Access options, it worked.